# How to run the notebook on google colab (throws an error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I understand very little in programming, so please answer as simply as possible. One of the notebooks on google colab throws an error. I just want to run this demo. I am attaching a screenshot, a link and the code of error.

[image: Screenshot]

[Link to the notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/magenta/ddsp/blob/master/ddsp/colab/demos/timbre_transfer.ipynb)

`ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 has requirement h5py~=3.1.0, but you'll have h5py 2.10.0 which is incompatible.`

Answer (score 0):

The versions are clashing.

**To fix the error, run these two commands in a cell before running other cells of the notebook:**

> 1. Install compatible TensorFlow version :

```
     !pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

> 2. Install compatible h5py version

```
     !pip install h5py==2.7.0
```